# How to specify default options for figure environment?

Tags: floats, formatting, positioning, preamble

More specifically, how can I set in the preamble the default options for the figure environment to `[htb]`? I am trying to separate content from format as much as possible and want to avoid writing `\begin{figure}[htb]` every time I declare a figure.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! In preamble put `\def\fps@figure{htb}`, of course inside `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Comment: In addition, `\def\fps@table{htb}` should do the same for tables.

Comment: @Zarko it works, thanks! Could you write this outside of a comment so that I can mark the question as answered? And thanks TukieMonster as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Positioning of floats (for figures, etc) you can set in preamble as

```
\makeatletter% because def contain @ 
    \def\fps@figure{hbt}
    \def\fps@table{hbt}
\makeatother
```

or even better

```
\makeatletter% because def contain @ 
    \def\fps@figure{hbtp}
    \def\fps@table{hbtp}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 2):

Load the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) and use `\floatplacement{<float>}{<specs>}`:

```
\usepackage{float}
\floatplacement{figure}{htb}
```